# Set operation to divide lists by one another in Scala

Tags: scala, set

Right now I have 2 lists in Scala:

```
val one = List(50, 10, 17, 8, 16)
val two = List(582, 180, 174, 159, 158)
```

These lists are going to be of the same length, and right now I'm looking to divide each element of the first list by a corresponding element in the second. In other words, I want a list that consists of:

```
List(50/582, 10/180, etc...)
```

Is there a set operation that accomplishes this that can be done without looping?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the zip function.

```
val one = List(50, 10, 17, 8, 16)
val two = List(582, 180, 174, 159, 158)
one.zip(two).map {
      case (a, b) => a.toDouble/b.toDouble
     }
```